# How to declare a function in LLVM and define it later

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

How can I declare a function in LLVM (with a specific signature) and create a call to it, e.g.

```
llvm::Value* return = m_builder.CreateCall( function, arguments );
```

but then define the body of the function later (which must be an InlineAsm function) ?

I'm later accessing the functions in a module in the following way

```
for (llvm::Module::iterator it = mod->begin(), end = mod->end(); it != end; ++it) 
{
     if( needsImplementation(it) ) {
        llvm::InlineAsm* inlineCall = ...
        it.body = inlineCall // This doesn't exist, pseudocode for what I need
     }
}
```

Since the signature is the same this should be possible I believe.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the "Kaleidoscope: Code generation to LLVM IR" manual: http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl3.html

> 3.4. Function Code Generation
>
> Code generation for prototypes and functions must handle a number of details, which make their code less beautiful than expression code generation, but allows us to illustrate some important points. First, lets talk about code generation for prototypes: **they are used both for function bodies and external function declarations**. The code starts with:

```
Function *PrototypeAST::Codegen() {
  // Make the function type:  double(double,double) etc.
  std::vector<Type*> Doubles(Args.size(),
                             Type::getDoubleTy(getGlobalContext()));
  FunctionType *FT = FunctionType::get(Type::getDoubleTy(getGlobalContext()),
                                       Doubles, false);

  Function *F = Function::Create(FT, Function::ExternalLinkage, Name, TheModule);
```

Later, when you want to add IR to the function you should get its declaration from the module: `TheModule->getFunction(Name);` and  add a BasicBlock:

```
BasicBlock *BB = BasicBlock::Create(getGlobalContext(), "entry", TheFunction);
Builder.SetInsertPoint(BB);
```

PS: answer is untested and answerer is not expert in LLVM.

PPS: For InlineAsm function, as I think after [doing searches with MetaGer](http://code.metager.de/source/search?q=InlineAsm%3A%3Aget&defs=&refs=&path=llvm&hist=&type=), you can't declare function as cited from Kaleidoscope. The only way is to have  `InlineAsm` function created at the place of call. Example of such usage is here: [CyanogenMod/android/art/compiler/llvm/runtime_support_builder_x86.cc#44](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/CyanogenMod/android/art/compiler/llvm/runtime_support_builder_x86.cc#44)

```
44 Value* RuntimeSupportBuilderX86::EmitGetCurrentThread() {
45  Function* ori_func = GetRuntimeSupportFunction(runtime_support::GetCurrentThread);
          //  ^^^^^ this is used only to know right Type of Function.
46  std::string inline_asm(StringPrintf("mov %%fs:%d, $0", Thread::SelfOffset().Int32Value()));  // <<< define the body of InlineAsm
47  InlineAsm* func = InlineAsm::get(ori_func->getFunctionType(), inline_asm, "=r", false);  // << Create InlineAsm function
48  CallInst* thread = irb_.CreateCall(func); // << Call it
```

Comment: The updated link to the tutorial is: https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl03.html